# Websocket with NestJs and Angular

Tags: angular, sockets, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I'm trying to implement a websocket between my NestJs server and my angular app.

I red the official NestJs documentation here : https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways

I can open the communicaiton between the two entities but I'm not able to send event ..

**Server Gateway**

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class SsgGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection {

    private logger: Logger = new Logger('SsgGateway');

    @WebSocketServer() wss: Server

    afterInit(server: any) {
        this.logger.log('Websocket gateway initialized')
    }

    handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
        this.logger.log("Client connected")
    }

    @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
    handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string): WsResponse<string> {
        this.wss.emit('msgToClient', payload)
    }
}
```

- I naturaly imported my SsgGateway into the app.module and enableCors
- afterInit is triggered during the server start (npm run:start)
- handleConnection is getting the client connexion when it starts ("Client connected")

Now, my client is not able to send any message through my socket. I tried with two different packages but unfortunately it is not working ..

The package installed are :

- socket.io-client
- ngx-socket-io

Here's the solution implemented client-side with **socket.io-client** :

**Service**

```
export class WebsocketService {

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io('ws://localhost:3000')
  }

  socket: any;

  listen(eventName: string) {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      this.socket.on(eventName, (data) => {
        subscriber.next(data);
      })
    });
  }

  emit(eventName: string, data: any) {
    this.socket.emit(eventName, data);
  }

}
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'websocket';

  constructor(private ws: WebsocketService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Listen to websocket event
    this.ws.listen('msgToClient').subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  send() {
    this.ws.emit('msgToServer', "test");
  }

}
```

I bind an htlm button that trigger the "send" event but I never get any data from my websocket.

Now, this is the solution tried with the package **ngx-socket-io** :

**Module**

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {  } };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
  ],
  providers: [AppService, WebsocketService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Service**

```
  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit('msgToServer', msg);
  }

  getMessage() {
    return this.socket.fromEvent('msgToClient').pipe(map((data: {}) => data));
  }
```

**Component**

```
  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getMessage().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
     })
  }

  send() {
    this.appService.sendMessage("test")
  }
```

I'm not even talking about the use of namespace which seems rather complicated to use.

A working example of Websocket with Angular and NestJs would be wonderful!

Thank you very much guys !

Comment: What are your socket.io versions?

Comment: I went too fast, it is indeed a version problem. @nestjs/platform-socket.io currently depends on socket.io v2.3 and socket.io v3.0 client and server are not backward compatible. However, you can still implement a custom adapter to use socket.io v3.0. Please refer to this issue for further information.

Answer (score 1):

- In server gateway, you are using the `emit`  that should not be.
- In server gateway, use `return`.

```
    @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
    handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string): WsResponse<string> {
        return { event: 'msgToClient', data: payload };
    }
```

*( I know it's too late to receive the answer, but someone else may find it useful )*